# arraylist size exception

Tags: java

```
for(int i=0;i<charset.size();i++)
{
    for(int j=0;i<charset.size();j++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<charset.size();k++)
        {
            String plaintext= charset.get(i)+charset.get(j)+charset.get(k);


            String hashtext=CreateHash.returnString(plaintext);

            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/root/MD5List.txt", true)); //opens file
            bw.write(plaintext+" = "+hashtext);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.close();
        }
    }
}
```

`arraylist` size is 10. When I run this program, I get a stacktrace:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10
>           at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:571)
>           at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:349)
>           at MD5HashTable.Hash.main(Hash.java:57)
>       Java Result: 1

Since the variable k is clearly less than the size of the `arraylist`, why do I get this error?

Comment: what you wanna do? same name three arraylist????

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo. In the `j` loop, you're testing `i`:

```
i<charset.size();
```

so `j` continues to increment. You want to test `j`:

```
j<charset.size();
```

Comment: Hahaha lol. This is why it is good to use descriptive variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to use 


  for(int i=0;i<charset.size();i++)
       {
        for(int j=0;j<charset.size();j++)
        {
```